# In my index section (Nomenclature) of my thesis file, a long sentence exceeds the page width and gets cut off. How do I fit the whole sentence?

Tags: line-breaking, makeindex

I have attached a picture of the problem.

My index Latex code is given below, I have included this file in my main thesis file latex window, from where I quick build it. I am using Texmaker compiler.

How can I correct the complication?[image: problem description image]`

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{center}
{\vspace{4cm} {\textbf{\LARGE{Nomenclature}}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
\begin{longtable}{l l}
%\begin{sloppypar}
$u,v$   &:velocity components along x- and y- axes \\ \\
$u_{w}$ &:velocity of the stretching sheet\\  \\
$x,y$   &:Cartesian coordinates (x-axis is aligned along the stretching surface and y-axis is normal to it)\\ \\
\textbf{Greek Symbols}\\ \\
$\alpha$  &:thermal diffusivity \\ \\
$(\rho c)_{p}$  &:effective heat capacity of the nanoparticle material \\ \\
$\varepsilon$   &:ratio between the effective heat capacity of the nanoparticle material and heat capacity of the fluid \\ \\
$\tau$  &:shearing stress\\ \\
$\tau_{s}$  &:reference shear stress\\ \\
\textbf{Subscript}\\ \\
$p$                                  &:nanoparticle\\ \\
$f$                                  &:base fluid\\ \\
\textbf{Superscript}\\ \\
%$n$  
%\end{sloppypar}                         &:Time level discritization\\ \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation.

Comment: Apart from that, here's hints: go to > https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables > Ctrl+F > "break". I suspect your question might not get an answer, since this has been answered on tex.se before. Do an internet search for "latex table automatic linebreak" and you will be directed to the relevant questions. Good learning!

Comment: Not related to your question, but I should really delete al those colons.

Comment: Your `longtable` has both columns specified with `l` (left-aligned, no line break), so long content can't fit. Try changing the second `l` to something like `p{.75\linewidth}` (replace fraction as appropriate).